# How to use a class type as a typed variable? (Typescript)

Tags: typescript

Lets say you have an interface then classes that implement it.

```
interface A { /*do stuff*/ }

class B implements A { /*do stuff*/ }

class C implements A { /*do stuff*/ }
```

Then if you have a variable that can store the class type, not a specific instance of an object, what do you put as the type?

```
let x: Something = B; // or C
```

I know for objects you can use typeof, but for interfaces you can't. However I am able to specify variables to store implementations of interfaces so I don't see why I shouldn't be able to store classes of an interface.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a constructor signature (similar to a function signature, but with a `new` in front of it):

```
interface A { /*do stuff*/ }

class B implements A { /*do stuff*/ }

class C implements A { /*do stuff*/ }


let x: new () => A = B;
let x2: new () => A = C;
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgILIN7IPQCoAmA9sgM5gCuMMu2yAvgLABQzCANnCScgELLABbAA5sIAiOG7oseIqQpUa9Zqw5dkAYX7DR4yWkw4CxMpWq1GLK6LDIAHgC5kICAHdkACgCUyALwA+A19eAG5mG3sAJicXd28-QPRgjRCgA)